# How do I allow visitors on my site to share my photos on their facebook news feed?

Tags: facebook

How do I allow visitors on my site to share **my photos, on their Facebook** wall/news feed?

I see that there is a "share" or "like" option from Facebook but that seems to share the whole page.

I would like to have it so that each picture has a small Facebook icon next to it and when they click it, that **specific image only** is added to their Facebook news feed/wall.

My site is in ASP.NET 3.5 using C#. I can develop in C# so if that is a route to what I am trying to achieve that is fine.

I did see this question and answer:
[How to post news feed in facebook from my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217925/how-to-post-news-feed-in-facebook-from-my-site)

Is this still the correct way to do this? Are there any examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What people can do is share the page link, and from that page facebook lets you select a photograph to represent it. Or you can write a routine for the users that needs to connect to facebook and it is prepared to share a photo on their wall each time you select that photo for facebook. For doing this you are going to need to use the google api and your own source code that allows it.

Comment: The images that represent the page don't look like images people would really be able to look at well. Google api? Why google? Are there any examples of this?